# Inconsistent spacing in table environment - first page only

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm trying to use LaTeX to make automatically generated box labels for large product orders for one of our customers that requires different packaging. All the non-tex coding is working so far and the files look as I expect. For the tex itself, I'm having an issue where the first page is oddly compressed relative to the other pages. I've been working on it all week and I can't see anything in the code that would be causing this?

Style file:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{nopageno}
\RequirePackage{anyfontsize}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage[paperwidth=8in, paperheight=4in, margin=0.5in, bmargin = 0.69in]{geometry} %1/2 margin on top of zprinter
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\savegeometry{zebra4x8}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\sto{\fontsize{12pt}{15pt}\selectfont}
\makeatother 

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ide{\fontsize{14pt}{17pt}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fote{\fontsize{13pt}{17pt}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ite{\fontsize{16pt}{19pt}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\setmainfont{Calibri}

\newcommand\twodigits[1]{%
   \ifnum#1<10 0#1\else #1\fi
}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\specialstock}[9]{
\newpage
\vspace*{\fill}
\bigskip\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{p{.88 in} p{3 in} p{0.63 in} p{0.94in} p{0.69 in}}
\multirow[t]{2}{*}{\sto Customer:}  & \sto\textbf{Special Customer}                     & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2.25in}{\ide #3}}}                                     \\
                                        & \sto\textbf{PH\#: 8005555555}                                     & \multicolumn{3}{l}{}                                                                                              \\ \cline{3-5} 
\multirow[t]{4}{*}{\sto Ship To:}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\sto Location Name}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ite Size\#}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ite Qty (pcs)}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ite LF}\\ \cline{3-5} 
                                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\sto 1234 Main Street}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ite \twodigits{#4}}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ite #5}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ite #6}\\ \cline{3-5} 
                                        & \sto City, ST                                                     & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\multirow{4}{*}{}}                                                                          \\
                                        & \sto Contact: Accounts Payable                                        & \multicolumn{3}{l}{}                                                                                              \\
                                        & \sto PO\#: #1 SO\#: #2                                        & \multicolumn{3}{l}{}                                                                                                      \\
                                        & \sto Reference: Tag No (If applicable)                                & \multicolumn{3}{l}{}           \\                                                            
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newline
\null\hfill \fote \textbf{#7 \quad Box #8 of #9}
}
```

Tex for the test label:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{special_labels}
\def\arraystretch{1}

\begin{document}


\specialstock{1234567}{987654}{Dim" Material Finishes Specs w/ Finish Options ProdName}{6}{50}{150}{Example Tag}{1}{6}
\specialstock{1234567}{987654}{Dim" Material Finishes Specs w/ Finish Options ProdName}{6}{50}{150}{Example Tag}{1}{6}
\specialstock{1234567}{987654}{Dim" Material Finishes Specs w/ Finish Options ProdName}{6}{50}{150}{Example Tag}{1}{6}
\specialstock{1234567}{987654}{Dim" Material Finishes Specs w/ Finish Options ProdName}{6}{50}{150}{Example Tag}{1}{6}
\specialstock{1234567}{987654}{Dim" Material Finishes Specs w/ Finish Options ProdName}{6}{50}{150}{Example Tag}{1}{6}
\specialstock{1234567}{987654}{Dim" Material Finishes Specs w/ Finish Options ProdName}{6}{50}{150}{Example Tag}{1}{6}


\end{document}
```

The output ends up looking like this:
[image]

where the first page, and ONLY the first page, is oddly smashed together. Every other page looks just fine.

I don't see anything in the code that would cause this, and all sorts of trying to move where the newpage is called, mess with the vspace, and add the tabular to a table environment have backfired spectacularly.

I'm open to a new way of creating the same result as the second page if need be - the most important thing is that the output is exactly the same as the second page, which matches our existing printed labels in format and margins.

Comment: Are you using `xelatex` or `lualatex` to compile this file?

Comment: the starting fontsize is 10pt, and after the first page it is 13pt/17pt because of the \fote command at the end of your command.

Comment: @JamesT I am compiling with xelatex

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That....makes sense. Let me see if I can then fix it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was the answer. I thought that calling a text size for each part would be enough. Thank you so much!

Comment: you are setting the other sizes only inside the tabular, that doesn't affect the normal, overall baselineskip of a tabular.

Comment: `\vspace*{\fill}
\newline
\null` is a rather strange construct, are you sure that does what you intend?